# osx 10.12.6 "Tor browser quit unexpectedly"

Tags: mac

After installing osx 10.12.6 I keep getting "Tor browser quit unexpectedly" every time I try to open it. Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks in advance :)

Hi. I just noticed that the Tor data folder in library/application support is missing - even when I uninstal then re install Tor. Anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was driving me mad. In the end I looked to see if there was any process running already, and sure enough, under Activity Monitor I could see a Tor process running. It had been running for ages. I killed that and now I have no problem starting Tor.

MacOS 10.12.6 TorBrowser 7.0.8